# MySQL Count per Quarter per Year, with 0 count

Tags: mysql, sql, date, temp-tables

I've got a table with luggage, with the columns:

**status(VARCHAR)** - ("lost", "found" etc.)

**datefound(DATE)** - (YYYY-MM-DD)

---

**My Luggage table:**

```
   -------------------------------------------
  | status | otherattributes |   datefound    |
   -------------------------------------------
  | lost   | ............... |   2014-11-17   |
  | found  | ............... |   2015-05-28   |
  | lost   | ............... |   2016-11-17   |
  | lost   | ............... |   2015-10-20   |
                     etc..
```

I would like to COUNT the luggage pieces with the status '**lost**' in a table per quarter, per year. 
While ALSO returning quarters where there are no '**lost**' pieces (count = 0).

### What I want:

**The desired table will look kind of like this:**

```
   ------------------------------
  | year | quarter | amountlost |
   ------------------------------
  | 2014 |    1    |     23     |
  | 2014 |    2    |     41     |
  | 2014 |    3    |      0     |
  | 2014 |    4    |     12     |
  | 2015 |    1    |     32     |
  | 2015 |    2    |      0     |
  | 2015 |    3    |      9     |
  | 2015 |    4    |     27     |
  | 2016 |    1    |     53     |
  | 2016 |    2    |     24     |
  | 2016 |    3    |     11     |
  | 2016 |    4    |      0     |
   ------------------------------
```

---

### What I have now:

I've currently got a query, but it doesn't return years + quarters with a COUNT of 0. I've tried using temporary tables but I just cannot get it work..

**Current query I'm working with:**

(doesn't give desired result)

`SELECT YEAR(datefound) AS year, 
        QUARTER(datefound) AS quarter, 
        COUNT(status) AS amountlost
FROM luggage
WHERE status = 'lost'
GROUP BY YEAR(datefound), QUARTER(datefound)
ORDER BY YEAR(datefound), QUARTER(datefound)`

**Resulting in (not desired):**

```
   ------------------------------
  | year | quarter | amountlost |
   ------------------------------
  | 2014 |    4    |     10     |
  | 2015 |    1    |     32     |
  | 2015 |    2    |      0     |
  | 2015 |    3    |      9     |
  | 2015 |    4    |     27     |
  | 2016 |    1    |     53     |
   ------------------------------
```

Above resulting table **missing quarters of 2014 and 2016**, which would result in a 0 count @ amountlost.

Hope someone can help me out with a query (perhaps with temp tables?) that provides me with the desired table!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a case where you have two choices.  The easier is when your input data has all the years and quarters, but the `where` clause is filtering them out.  Then you can just switch to conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT YEAR(datefound) AS year, 
       QUARTER(datefound) AS quarter, 
       SUM(status = 'lost') AS amountlost
FROM luggage
GROUP BY YEAR(datefound), QUARTER(datefound)
ORDER BY YEAR(datefound), QUARTER(datefound);
```

If this doesn't work, then you need to generate the possible rows and then add the additional information.  Assuming there are representatives for each year and quarter in the data:

```
SELECT y.yyyy, q.qq, COUNT(l.status) as AmountLost
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(datefound) as yyyy FROM luggage) y CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT DISTINCT QUARTER(datefound) as qq FROM LUGGAGE) q LEFT JOIN
     luggage l
     ON YEAR(l.datefound) = y.yyyy AND QUARTER(l.datefound) = q.qq AND
        l.status = 'lost'
GROUP BY y.yyyy, q.qq;
```

If your data is not even complete in that respect, then you need to generate the rows that you want.  Something like:

```
SELECT yq.yyyy, yq.qq, COUNT(l.status) as AmountLost
FROM (SELECT 2014 as yyyy, 1 as qq  UNION ALL
      SELECT 2014, 2 UNION ALL
      . . .
     ) yq LEFT JOIN
     luggage l
     ON YEAR(l.datefound) = yq.yyyy AND QUARTER(l.datefound) = yq.qq AND
        l.status = 'lost'
GROUP BY yq.yyyy, yq.qq;
```

Note:  You may already have a table with the appropriate years and quarters for the report.  If so you can use that.  If you have a numbers table of some sort, that can also be used (with some additional logic).

Comment: The second one worked wonders man, thanks a bunch!

I slightly altered it to only count status = 'lost' , instead of counting all the statuses.



----------------



     `SELECT y.yyyy, q.qq, coalesce(SUM(status = 'lost'), 0) as Amountlost
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(datefound) as yyyy FROM luggage) y CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT DISTINCT QUARTER(datefound) as qq FROM LUGGAGE) q LEFT JOIN
     luggage l
     ON YEAR(l.datefound) = y.yyyy AND QUARTER(l.datefound) = q.qq
GROUP BY y.yyyy, q.qq;`

------- **coalesce(SUM(status = 'lost'), 0) as Amountlost** instead of **COUNT(l.status) as AmountLost**